# Edit Product page file upload button

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options, file-upload

I was wondering if someone knows how i can customize the "browse" (change language, and add some css to it ) button for uploading a file on the product page(custom options)

The customer should be able to upload multiple files, no you can only upload 1?

I also want to hide the max allowed image dimensions.

Thanks!

Comment: you should be able to change the css of that button in the styles.css

Comment: Awesome thanks Thomas, any idea how i can modify it so that the customer can upload multiple files?

Comment: maybe check these two http://inchoo.net/magento/file-upload-in-magento/ and that one http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/multiple-file-upload-frontend-63-nbsp--47672.html

Comment: Thanks! i found this http://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/magento-custom-options-multiple-file-upload-problem-solution.html i will try it later tonight hopefully it will work:)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked on my local version so it would be changing the button styling etc. in the Styles.css and then change the following file magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\File.php

where you find this line

```
if (!$upload->receive()) {
```

and change it to this one

```
if (!$upload->receive($file)) {
```

Comment: Just checked for the PHP file. Unfortunately i cant find that line of code in the file.php? (i used the search function of my text editor)  This is the path i used /domains/ideezmedia.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/file.php   my magento version is 1.9.1.0

Comment: At line 145 Check there

Comment: Nope not there, i even tried searching with phrases of that line of code, nothing. Very strange

Comment: I have a look again for it also

Comment: Magento_Folder/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/ and then there in any php file otherwise try to download the file again as it probably was deleted then

Comment: Tried pretty much everything, i read somewhere that after the magento 1.4 update they overhauled the code of those files? I downloaded the magento 1.4 file.php and compared it to mine, the markup an code was totally different. if (!$upload->receive()) { was indeed in the 1.4 file mot not mine (1.9)

Comment: So still doesn't work ?